# Displaying the submit button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this code which I want the submit button to display only when all the fields are not empty but it's not working.

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="title" placeholder="TITLE" />
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" class="text" placeholder="TAGS" />
    <span id="advance"></span>
</form>
<script src="js/jscript.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (($("#comment").val() !== "") && ($("#title").val() !== "") && ($("#tags").val() !== "")) {
            $('#advance').html("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='upload' value='ADVANCE' />");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would bind an event handler to the "change"(or "keyup") JavaScript event.
When changing on the input, it will trigger the function.

```
$(document).on('change','#my_form', function() {
    if (($("#comment").val() !== "") && ($("#title").val() !== "") && ($("#tags").val() !== "")) {
        $('#advance').html("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='upload' value='ADVANCE' />");
    }
});
```

And it can update the funciton for check isfill:

```
$(document).on('change','#my_form', function() {
  var allFilled = true;

  $(':input:not(:button)').each(function(index, element) {
    if (element.value === '')
      allFilled = false;
   });

  $('#advance').html("");
  if(allFilled)
    $('#advance').html("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='upload' value='ADVANCE' />");     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready` only fires once when the page is finished rendering.

You need to attach to the `onfocus`, `onblur`, or `onchange` event on the form fields to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/) an [input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16945638/2813224) or [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event on document.

```
$(document).on('input', function(e) {
    // your original code
});
```

### SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input', function(e) {
    if (($("#title").val() !== "") && ($("textarea").val() !== "") && ($("#tags").val() !== "")) {
      $('#advance').html("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='upload' value='ADVANCE' />");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Added a little style because the alignment was annoying */

bady {
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
}
input,
textarea {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
input {
  width: 12em;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" name="form">
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="title" placeholder="TITLE" />
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" class="text" placeholder="TAGS" />
  <div id="advance"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS alternative:

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title');
var comment = document.getElementById('comment');
var tags = document.getElementById('tags');
var advance = document.getElementById('advance');

document.getElementById('my_form').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' || e.target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA')   
    if (title.value && comment.value && tags.value)
      advance.innerHTML = "<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='upload' value='ADVANCE' />";
});
```

```html
<form id="my_form">
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="title" placeholder="TITLE" />
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea" placeholder="COMMENT"></textarea>
  <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" class="text" placeholder="TAGS" />
  <span id="advance"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use another approach. Instead of outputting code with js, you can always have the  as you like directly in the html, and instead hiding or showing it with the help of js/css.

```
<form id="my_form">
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="title" placeholder="TITLE" />
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" class="text" placeholder="TAGS" />
  <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='upload' value='ADVANCE' style="display: none" />
</form>

<script src="js/jscript.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '#my_form', function() {
        if (($("#comment").val() == "") || ($("#title").val() == "") || ($("#tags").val() == "")) {
          $('#submit').css("display", "none");
        } else {
          $('#submit').css("display", "");
        }
      })
    });
</script>
```

Keep in mind that the change event fires after the input lose focus, so you might want to use another event.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/af5torcs/1/

Comment: $('#submit').css("display", "block"); better than  $('#submit').css("display", "");

Comment: How is displaying an inline element as a block element "better"?  
    $('#submit').css("display", "");   
Removes the display attribute altogether.